# In PHP, I invoke exit(1). How to get the status code in PHP?

Tags: php

In PHP, I have a Class name `CustomClass`, then I invoke `exit(1)`. On Destructor of `CustomClass`, how I get the status code of exit? I should get the parameter of `exit(1)`, which is `1`.

```
class CustomClass
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        //how to get the status code of exit() ?
        echo "exit code is? \n";
    }
}

try {
    $customObj = new CustomClass();

    throw New Exception('some error....');
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo "error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit(1);
}

echo "This echo will not output\n";
```

I expected to get the parameter of `exit(1)`, which is `1`.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-get-exit-status.php

Comment: Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php, it says: status
If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.

If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully. So maybe change exit(1) to exit("1");

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function uopz_get_exit_status()

Comment: @JureW The question is how to get the Status Code of exit().

Comment: And I answered it.  *If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting. If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed* So I proposed to use status as a string

Comment: @JureW I want to get the status code of exit, your solution is print the status code. It's different. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @sai, than try something like this: `function execute($StatusCode) { echo $StatusCode; }`
 `exit(execute(3)); // Will exit and print 3`

Comment: @JureW That's what I want. Thank You. It's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its working (as written in the comment), I'll put an answer here, for better view:

PHP exit() will not print anything if you use it like exit(int), but if you pass a string, it will get printed:

> status If status is a string, this function prints the status just
>   before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

So a solution to print int on exit is to use a function:

```
function execute($statusCode) { 
    echo $statusCode; 
} 
exit(execute(3)); // Will exit and print 3
```

BR

Comment: It doesn't `exit` with status code `3` though. It also seems to solve a problem that doesn't have much to do with the question. I mean, if it works for OP, fine… but it would be interesting to have a solution for the actual question asked…

Comment: If you do want the status code 3 (or whatever) on the exit command, the solution would be to add a `return` to the function.

`function execute($statusCode) { 
    echo $statusCode; return $statusCode;
} 
exit(execute(3)); // Will print 3 and exit with code 3`